# Dividing a polynomial

Tags: polynomials

Let $f=a_{0}+a_{1}x+ ...+ a_{n}x^n$ be a polynomial in $Q[x]$

$f'=a_{1}+2a_{2}x+...+na_{n}x^{n-1}$

Show if $f$ is divisible by $(x-c)^2$ for some $c \in Q$ then $f'(c)=0$

My own thoughts:
If $(x-c)^2$ divides $f$ then the remainder is 0 after division. But don't know how to start this really..

Comment: Write $f(x) = (x-c)^2g(x)$, then...

Comment: Start with $f(x)=(x-c)^2$ itself and compute. Then generalise to $f(x)=(x-c)^2g(x)$.

Comment: Yes I can see that

Comment: And from product rule $f'(c)=0$ right?

Answer (score 2):

If $f$ is divisible by $(x-c)^2$, then $f(x)=(x-c)^2g(x)$ for some polynomial $g(x)$, as suggested in the comments. Taking the derivative
$$f'(x)=2(x-c)g(x)+(x-c)^2g'(x).
$$
Then $f'(c)=0$. In fact, if $f$ is divisible by $(x-c)^n$  for $n>1$, $f'(c)=0$.